# Why is my column format inconsistent?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently experimenting with using formula in VBA in which I have a Sheet with 3 columns. One for Year, Month, and Day respectively. Together they will form a pseudo-date in another column using the formula:

```
=I4& "/" &H4& "/" &G4
```

Then in another sheet I have a column which will get the pseudo-date and copy it via Vlookup in VBA.

Before I used VBA I placed the formula in the column itself and it works fine. It is only when I tried to place it in VBA, weirdness happens.

Some cells have the proper format while some defaults to a string of numbers.
Upon closer observation, dates with days that are less than 13 ends up getting defaulted to number strings

Example: Some cells have numbers 42741, etc. while some have proper format 20/6/2017.

I've made sure that the Vlookup column is using the same format as the pseudo-date column which is general and the problem still exists.

When I changed the format into date, those who has their date defaulted to number strings end up having the days and months reversed.
(1/8/2017 becomes 8/1/2017 and so on). Once again those with days 13 and over are unaffected.

I even tried to set the a number format on the Vlookup column but once again no luck. Here is the code for reference.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("a4:a9999")) Is Nothing Then
       With Me.Range("d4:d9999")
           .Formula = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A4,ProjectEntry,10,FALSE)),"""",VLOOKUP(A4,ProjectEntry,10,FALSE))"
           .Value = .Value
           .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
       End With
```

The question now is, why is Excel acting all bonkers over this date issue?

Edit: I figured out a way on how to make sure the date format is similar on both ends.

The code now uses copy and paste as values to get the data I want.

```
With Me.Range("d4:d9999")
    .Formula = "=IF(ISNA(INDEX(ProjectEntry,MATCH(A4,ProjectEntry[Project No],FALSE),10)),"""",INDEX(ProjectEntry,MATCH(A4,ProjectEntry[Project No],FALSE),10))"
    .Copy
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
 End With
```

However the issue I have with this is that it leaves behind the copy box (the moving dotted lines box that appears when you copy cell(s)) and it always jump to the first row I declared in the code (row 4). I do not want to keep scrolling down to the end every time I enter my data. Is there a way to remove this in my code?

Comment: Excel is getting confused about the format (are the days first, or the months)? Try feeding it ISO 8601, as it's unambiguous (`yyyy-MM-dd`), regardless of how you choose to format the date visually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel, a date is a number. Excel counts the days since 31 Dec 1899. Then it displays that number in a way that looks to you like a date. Excel does that in reverse gear, too. If you enter something that looks to it like a date it will convert your entry into a number that represents that date. I won't go into what looks to Excel like a date but as a hint, it has to do with your regional settings.

Now, your "pseudo-date" should be '= Date(G4, H4, I4)' (sequence is Year, Month, Day). The result is a number. Presume that you have the Date() function in K4 and you might format K4 as "dd/mm/yyyy" (without the quotation marks) and that is what the cell will show. All the while its value will be a number representing the displayed date.

Now that you have proper values you can start using VLookup or other functions. That is another subject - if you have problems with it.

Comment: I don't understand... I tried using the formula in VBA and even tried combining with what I have. But all I get is just #NAME? Can you elaborate more or give example cuz I'm lost.

Comment: I apoligise! `DateSerial()` is a VBA function. The worksheet equivalent is simly `Date()`, taking the same 3 arguments, Year, Month, Day - in that sequence. I have corrected this in my above post.

Comment: all is well. finally this issue is done. thanks a lot.

Comment: Wonderful. Sorry I delayed you. Have a great day.